# Differences between (R)Unified Process And Extreme Programming

Tags: extreme-programming, rational-unified-process

I've searched for at question like this and i dont think there are one.

As the title says... I know there are huge differences between how to do things in (R)UP  and in XP as a way of developing systems, but what are the really?
I'm trying to write a nice explanation that i can give to other people so they hopefully easy can understand the differences.

I want to compare the following subjects:

- Design
- Documentation
- Prototyping
- User involvement
- Usability
- Technical quality
- Test

I'm not trying to start a discussion, just want to know if you know any good sites that could have the information i'm looking for or if you have a answer for one of the subjects. I have allready written some of it myself but due to the fact that i dont want it to be a subjective comparison, i then ask you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RUP and XP are not mutually exclusive. Comparing the two is like comparing apples and oranges -- you can enjoy both. Many companies following RUP choose to include some or all of XP practices.

For the basics, the wikipedia articles are a good start:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Unified_Process
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming_practices

Answer (score 1):

You might find this useful
[XP vs RUP](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/zohair/Documents/CSC541/Chap2-SWE%20processes/XP%20vs%20RUP.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: Thank you. I have allready fund this but again thanks for the answer :)